# Help with hardwired CO Detectors

Tags: wiring, alarm, carbon-monoxide

I have three CO sensors that are over 10 years old and two are beeping to let me know they have gone bad. They are hard-wired into a Concord 4 Series box. The previous owners had a robust alarm system that we are not using that is also wired into the box.

When I had an electrician here for something unrelated, I asked if he could replace and he noted they should not be high up on the wall as they are now. He recommended to instead just get the kind you plug into an outlet. This is fine, but he also said he could not help disconnect them from the Concord series 4 box and to call an alarm company. I was about to just cut all power to this box but realized that would also disable my smoke detectors.

Does anyone know how I can figure out which of these wires are for CO2 sensors? If not, I plan to just disconnect the wires going into the actual CO detectors and use wire nuts to terminate them.

[Images of wiring](https://imgur.com/a/9zcGJjb)

Comment: Not sure why you aren't just getting new combination smoke/CO detectors and abandoning your abandoned security system entirely...

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting power to the current CO sensors, just leave the alarm system box as is, and just install new detectors to replace the old ones.

I don't know where you live, but in my state plug-in detectors are not allowed as primary detectors. Besides that they are not safe, since anyone can disconnect them because of "nuisance noise", a.k.a. the detector telling you it detected a killer gas in your house.

Comment: I am struggling to find 12/24 v replacements I currently have these installed and I read online they stopped making them, so any being sold.might already be a few years old. https://www.cityelectricsupply.com/edwards-260-co-carbon-monoxide-detector?utm_term=&utm_campaign=802:+Evergreen+%7C+Performance+Max+%7C+All+Products&utm_source=adwords&utm_medium=ppc&hsa_acc=3560235644&hsa_cam=18073715267&hsa_grp=&hsa_ad=&hsa_src=x&hsa_tgt=&hsa_kw=&hsa_mt=&hsa_net=adwords&hsa_ver=3&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA_tuuBhAUEiwAvxkgTjwMC7hzFdsMCHmBqolucoh72IsLbSG3-F1Vp6KZQnJhI0y7Ay5KYxoChVgQAvD_BwE